# How to add json string data from url to an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have received json string that looks like a javascript array from an url (example.com/data)

```
["apple","orange","mango","banana"]
```

How can I store this data to an array in my js file ? For eg. I have a variable called `fruitArray` and I want to fill this variable with data I received from the url so that it will looks like below :

```
var fruitArray = ["apple","orange","mango","banana"]; // contains array from the url
```

Comment: Please update the question with the url.

Comment: Please share a working snippet demonstrating your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getJSON load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request.

Data that is sent to the server is appended to the URL as a query string. If the value of the data parameter is a plain object, it is converted to a string and url-encoded before it is appended to the URL.

```
var myArray;

$.getJSON( "your URL", function( json ) {
  myArray = json;
 });
```

Comment: While this code-only post might answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so. This will help future users evaluate the answer for their situation.

Answer (score 0):

see example

```
    var hege = ["Cecilie", "Lone"];
    var stale = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
    var children = hege.concat(stale); //this will add 2 arrays together
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an Ajax call 
on success method you can assign the result to your variable. 
If that's what you meant by your query.

Example

```
var yourvariable;
$.ajax
({
    url: "your URL"        
    , success: function(result)
    {
       yourvariable = result;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({ 
 type: 'GET', 
 url: actual_url, 
 data: paramters, 
 dataType:'json',
 success: function (data) { 
           var fruitArray = data                    
     }
});
```